# Marking job as ready for processing when dependent job finishes

Tags: database, architecture, workflow

What is the best way of marking job as ready for processing when its dependent job finishes successfully? Once all dependent jobs in table A for a specific job in table B finish I need to mark a job in table B as ready to process.

Table A :

| job_id | type | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | specific | completed |
| A2 | specific | completed |
| A3 | specific | in progress |
| A4 | other_type | completed |

Table B :

| job_id | status |
| --- | --- |
| B1 | queued |
| B2 | waiting |
| B3 | queued |

Dependency table :

| job_a_id | job_b_id |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 |
| A2 | B1 |
| A3 | B2 |
| A4 | B3 |

Since `A3` is not processed and `B2` is dependent of it, it's still in `waiting` state. Once `A3` finishes, `B2` can be marked as `queued`.

The jobs are processed simultaneously on different machines so getting current number of successful dependent jobs would not work as 2 machines can ask for info at the same time and both will get "2 jobs are not successful yet", so neither will mark the job as ready for processing. This can be solved via database lock, but is there a better way?

Millions of jobs get added everyday and a single job is dependent on hundreds of jobs.

Comment: Unless this is a learning assignment, a relational database wasn't designed to be a job scheduler.  A job scheduler has to be single-threaded to prevent the situation you described.